# Ressourcemonitor Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, performance-monitoring

Got a question about monitoring a process with the ressource monitor. 
I want to monitor the cpu usage and the memory usage of a process. Also I want to monitor the total cpu usage. But there are a lot of indicators and I'm not sure which one to pick. Which ones do I have to use?

Answer (score 0):

Woah... (as Joey Russo would say). This question is totally bogus.

Anyhoo... my suggestion would be to use Performance Monitor and check the "Show description" checkbox so that you can read what each counter is so that you can learn what each counter is measuring. That will give you invaluable insight so that you won't have to ask a question again that would be better answered through your own investigation and effort, which is afterall, the best way to learn.

Hopefully this answer has got you totally stoked, dude!

Comment: I wouldn't ask, if I had done that. But, the descriptions aren't that easy to understand.

Comment: And who is Joey Russo? ;-)

Comment: Oh, you haven't seen the "Blossom" television show? - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blossom_(TV_series)#Characters - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c5dCopAZaq8

Comment: I get that they're not all easy to understand but the key is to do some research on the ones you don't understand so that you learn what they are and will be better suited to troubleshoot your problem, with your own knowledge and experience. Performance monitoring is as much an art as it is science and each performance issue is unique. Now, if you tell us what kind of problem you're dealing with we can probably offer some guidance.

Comment: Whoa ;-) if that that question was a stupid question for you guys, so I'm sorry. But not every one of us is an expert or understands the deep technical descriptions

Comment: You misunderstood. I didn't say your question was stupid and I'm not suggesting that it is. I'm implying that this question is one of those questions that would better serve you by doing your own research. Progress comes from your own work and effort. Why not take a look at the various counters, read their descriptions, see if they fit your need, and then come back here with more in depth questions about specific counters?